# access token from auth0provider outside of react components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, auth0

I'm using the auth0 token provided by the user on login to make api calls via useAuth0.getTokenSilently.

In this example, `fetchTodoList`, `addTodoItem`, and `updateTodoItem` all require a token for authorization. I'd like to be able to extract these functions out in to a separate file (like `utils/api-client.js` and import them without having to explicitly pass in the token.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faCircle, faList } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import axios from 'axios'
import { queryCache, useMutation, useQuery } from 'react-query'
import { TodoItem } from '../models/TodoItem'
import { TodoInput } from './TodoInput'
import { TodoList as TodoListComponent } from './TodoList'
import { TodoListsContext } from '../store/todolists'
import { TodoListName } from './TodoListName'
import { TodoList } from '../models/TodoList'
import { useAuth0 } from '../utils/react-auth0-wrapper'

export const EditTodoList = () => {

  const { getTokenSilently } = useAuth0()

  const fetchTodoList = async (todoListId: number): Promise<TodoList> => {
    try {
      const token = await getTokenSilently!()

      const { data } = await axios.get(
        `/api/TodoLists/${todoListId}`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
          }
        }
      )
      return data
    } catch (error) {
      return error
    }
  }

  const addTodoItem = async (todoItem: TodoItem): Promise<TodoItem> => {
    try {
      const token = await getTokenSilently!()

      const { data } = await axios.post(
        '/api/TodoItems',
        todoItem,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          }
        }
      )
      return data
    } catch (addTodoListError) {
      return addTodoListError
    }
  }

  const updateTodoItem = async (todoItem: TodoItem) => {
    try {
      const token = await getTokenSilently!()

      const { data } = await axios.put(
        '/api/TodoItems',
        todoItem,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          }
        }
      )
      return data
    } catch (addTodoListError) {
      return addTodoListError
    }
  }

  const [updateTodoItemMutation] = useMutation(updateTodoItem, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryCache.refetchQueries(['todoList', todoListId])
    }
  })

  const [addTodoItemMutation] = useMutation(addTodoItem, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      console.log('success')
      queryCache.refetchQueries(['todoList', todoListId])
    }
  })

  const onAddTodoItem = async (todoItem: TodoItem) => {
    try {
      await addTodoItemMutation({ 
        ...todoItem, 
        todoListId: parseInt(todoListId, 10) 
      })
    } catch (error) {
      // Uh oh, something went wrong
    }
  }

  const { todoListId } = useParams()
  const { status, data: todoList, error } = useQuery(['todoList', todoListId], () => fetchTodoList(todoListId))
  const { todoLists, setTodoList } = useContext(TodoListsContext)
  const todoListIndex = todoLists.findIndex(
    list => todoListId === list.id.toString()
  )

  const setTodoItems = (todoItems: TodoItem[]) => {
    // if(todoList) {
    //   const list = { ...todoList, todoItems }
    //   setTodoList(todoListIndex, list)
    // }
  }

  const setTodoListName = (name: string) => {
    // setTodoList(todoListIndex, { ...todoList, name })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Link className="block flex align-items-center mt-8" to="/">
        <span className="fa-layers fa-fw fa-3x block m-auto group">
          <FontAwesomeIcon 
            icon={faCircle} 
            className="text-teal-500 transition-all duration-200 ease-in-out group-hover:text-teal-600" 
          />
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faList} inverse transform="shrink-8" />
        </span>
      </Link>

      {status === 'success' && !!todoList && (
        <>
          <TodoListName
            todoListName={todoList.name}
            setTodoListName={setTodoListName}
          />
          <TodoInput 
            onAddTodoItem={onAddTodoItem} 
          />

          <TodoListComponent
            todoItems={todoList.todoItems}
            setTodoItems={setTodoItems}
            updateTodo={updateTodoItemMutation}
          />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

Here's a link to the repo: https://github.com/gpspake/todo-client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, got it!

Now that I understand better, my real question was how to provide an auth0 token to axios requests such that they don't need to be declared in components.

The short answer:
Get the token when auth0 is initialized and register an [axios interceptor](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) to set that token as a header value for all axios requests.

The long answer (examples in typescript):

Declare a function that takes a token and registers an [axios interceptor](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors)

```js
const setAxiosTokenInterceptor = async (accessToken: string): Promise<void> => {
  axios.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
    const requestConfig = config
    if (accessToken) {
      requestConfig.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    } 
    return requestConfig
  })
}
```

In the auth0provider wrapper, when the auth0 client is initialized and authenticated, get the token with `getTokenSilently` and pass it to the `setAxiosTokenInterceptor` (Modified example from the [Auth0 React SDK Quickstart](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/01-login#install-the-auth0-react-wrapper)):

```
useEffect(() => {
    const initAuth0 = async () => {
        const auth0FromHook = await createAuth0Client(initOptions)
        setAuth0(auth0FromHook)

        if (window.location.search.includes('code=')) {
            const { appState } = await auth0FromHook.handleRedirectCallback()
            onRedirectCallback(appState)
        }

        auth0FromHook.isAuthenticated().then(
            async authenticated => {
                setIsAuthenticated(authenticated)
                if (authenticated) {
                    auth0FromHook.getUser().then(
                        auth0User => {
                            setUser(auth0User)
                        }
                    )
                    // get token and register interceptor
                    const token = await auth0FromHook.getTokenSilently()
                    setAxiosTokenInterceptor(token).then(
                        () => {setLoading(false)}
                    )
                }
            }
        )


    }
    initAuth0().catch()
}, [])
```

Calling `setLoading(false)` when the promise is resolved ensures that, if auth0 is finished loading, the interceptor has been registered. Since none of the components that make requests are rendered until auth0 is finished loading, this prevents any calls from being made without the token.

This allowed me to move all of my axios functions in to a separate file and import them in to the components need them. When any of these functions are called, the interceptor will add the token to the header
`utils/todo-client.ts`

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import { TodoList } from '../models/TodoList'
import { TodoItem } from '../models/TodoItem'

export const fetchTodoLists = async (): Promise<TodoList[]> => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      '/api/TodoLists'
    )
    return data
  } catch (error) {
    return error
  }
}

export const fetchTodoList = async (todoListId: number): Promise<TodoList> => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `/api/TodoLists/${todoListId}`
    )
    return data
  } catch (error) {
    return error
  }
}

export const addTodoItem = async (todoItem: TodoItem): Promise<TodoItem> => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      '/api/TodoItems',
      todoItem
    )
    return data
  } catch (addTodoListError) {
    return addTodoListError
  }
}
...
```

[Full source on github](https://github.com/gpspake/todo-client)

Comment: I understand the token will be set just once, at initialization of auth0? This means that when the token expires (short validity time or long running App) API requests will fail.

Comment: @HansBouwmeester this is a good point and something I probably need to take in to consideration. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

I was having a similar issue on how to use `getAccessTokenSilently` outside of a React component, what I ended up with was this:

My HTTP client wrapper

```
export class HttpClient {
  constructor() {
    HttpClient.instance = axios.create({ baseURL: process.env.API_BASE_URL });

    HttpClient.instance.interceptors.request.use(
      async config => {
        const token = await this.getToken();

        return {
          ...config,
          headers: { ...config.headers, Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
        };
      },
      error => {
        Promise.reject(error);
      },
    );

    return this;
  }

  setTokenGenerator(tokenGenerator) {
    this.tokenGenerator = tokenGenerator;
    return this;
  }

  getToken() {
    return this.tokenGenerator();
  }
}
```

On my App root, I pass the `getAccessTokenSilently` from auth0

```
 useEffect(() => {
    httpClient.setTokenGenerator(getAccessTokenSilently);
  }, [getAccessTokenSilently]);
```

And that's it!

You now have an `axios` instance ready to do authenticated requests with

Answer (score 4):

This is a variant of the answer by @james-quick, where I am using a "RequestFactory" to generate requests in the axios format, and then just adding the auth header from Auth0

I was facing the same issue, and I got around this limitation by moving all my API call logic into a custom hook that I created:

```
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import makeRequest from './axios';

export const useRequest = () => {
  const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();

  // memoized the function, as otherwise if the hook is used inside a useEffect, it will lead to an infinite loop
  const memoizedFn = useCallback(
    async (request) => {
      const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently({ audience: AUDIANCE })
      return makeRequest({
        ...request,
        headers: {
          ...request.headers,
          // Add the Authorization header to the existing headers
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      });
    },
    [isAuthenticated, getAccessTokenSilently]
  );
  return {
    requestMaker: memoizedFn,
  };
};

export default useRequest;
```

Usage Example:

```
 import { RequestFactory } from 'api/requestFactory';

 const MyAwesomeComponent = () => {
   const { requestMaker } = useRequest(); // Custom Hook
   ...
   requestMaker(QueueRequestFactory.create(queueName))
     .then((response) => {
       // Handle response here
       ...
     });
 }
```

RequestFactory defines and generates the request payload for my different API calls, for example:

```
export const create = (queueName) => ({ method: 'post', url: '/queue', data: { queueName } });
```

[Here](https://github.com/SimplQ/simplQ-frontend/pull/483) is a full Auth0 integration PR for reference.

Answer (score 4):

I like to have my API calls in their own directory (under `/api` for example) and have the code to call to the API be as small as possible. I took a similar approach to others on here, using Auth0, TypeScript, Axios (including an interceptor) and React hooks.

### The TLDR answer

Place your Axios interceptor within a hook, and then use that hook within  segmented API hooks (ie, `useUserApi`, `useArticleApi`, `useCommentApi` and so on). You can then cleanly call your API using Auth0.

### The long answer

Define your Axios hook, I've only covered the HTTP methods I'm currently using:

```
# src/api/useAxios.ts

import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

// We wrap Axios methods in a hook, so we can centrally handle adding auth tokens.
const useAxios = () => {
  const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();

  axios.interceptors.request.use(async (config: any) => {
    if (config.url.indexOf('http') === -1) {
      config.url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT}/${config.url}`;
    }

    if (typeof config.headers.Authorization === 'undefined') {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${await getAccessTokenSilently()}`;
    }
    return config;
  });

  return {
    get: async (url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<any> | undefined): Promise<AxiosResponse> => axios.get(url, config),
    delete: async (url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<any> | undefined): Promise<AxiosResponse> => axios.delete(url, config),
    post: async (url: string, data?: any, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<any> | undefined): Promise<AxiosResponse> => axios.post(url, data, config),
    put: async (url: string, data?: any, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<any> | undefined): Promise<AxiosResponse> => axios.put(url, data, config),
    patch: async (url: string, data?: any, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<any> | undefined): Promise<AxiosResponse> => axios.patch(url, data, config),
  }
};

export default useAxios;
```

What I'm doing here is adding a bearer token by calling `getAccessTokensSilently()` if one is not already defined. Additionally, if HTTP isn't present in my URL then I append the default API URL from my environment variables - this means I can keep my request short and not have to use the full URL every time.

Now I define a hook based on my user API as following:

```
# src/api/useUserApi.ts

import { UserInterface } from '[REDACTED]/types';
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import useAxios from './useAxios';

const useUserApi = () => {
  const { get, post, put } = useAxios();
  return {
    getUser: (id: string): Promise<AxiosResponse<UserInterface>> => get(`user/${id}`),
    putUser: (user: UserInterface) => put('user', user),
    postUser: (user: UserInterface) => post('user', user),
  }
};

export default useUserApi;
```

You can see I expose the underlying HTTP methods from Axios, and then use them in API specific scenarios, `getUser`, `putUser`, and `postUser`.

Now I can go ahead and call my API in some application logic, keeping the API code to the absolute minimum but still allowing full pass through and typing of the Axios objects.

```
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';
import useUserApi from '../../../api/useUserApi';

const LoginCallback = (): JSX.Element => {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const { user, isAuthenticated, isLoading } = useAuth0();
  const { getUser, putUser, postUser} = useUserApi();
  const saveUserToApi = async () => {
    if (!user?.sub) {
      throw new Error ('User does not have a sub');
    }

    // Try and find the user, if 404 then create a new one for this Auth0 sub
    try {
      const userResult = await getUser(user.sub);
      putUser(Object.assign(user, userResult.data));
      navigate('/');
    } catch (e: any) {
      if (e.response.status === 404) {
        postUser({
          id: user.sub,
          email: user.email,
          name: user.name,
          givenName: user.givenName,
          familyName: user.familyName,
          locale: user.locale,
        });
        navigate('/');
      }
    }
  }

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Logging you in...</div>;
  }

  if (isAuthenticated && user?.sub) {
    saveUserToApi();
    return <p>Saved</p>
  } else {
    return <p>An error occured whilst logging in.</p>;
  }
};

export default LoginCallback;
```

You can note the above `postUser`, `putUser` and `getUser` API requests are all one liners, with only the declaration (`const { getUser, putUser, postUser} = useUserApi();`) and import being required otherwise.

This answer is definitely standing on the shoulders of giants, but I thought it would be useful all the same to someone who likes to keep their API calls as clean as possible.

Comment: Do you still use this way of decoupling your Api ? how do you handle loaders for example when you use `putUser` or `getUser` methods in component ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure why you couldn't access the token inside of your individual functions? Is it because they wouldn't be React function components but just regular functions?

One of the things I have done is create a useFetch hook that can get the user token and attach it to a request itself. Then, instead of exporting those functions specifically,I can just call this new fetch hook.  Here's an example of what I mean.

```
import React from "react"
import { useAuth0 } from "../utils/auth"

const useFetch = () => {
  const [response, setResponse] = React.useState(null)
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null)
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false)
  const { getTokenSilently } = useAuth0()

  const fetchData = async (url, method, body, authenticated, options = {}) => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    try {
      if (authenticated) {
        const token = await getTokenSilently()
        if (!options.headers) {
          options.headers = {}
        }
        options.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`
      }
      options.method = method
      if (method !== "GET") {
        options.body = JSON.stringify(body)
      }
      const res = await fetch(url, options)
      const json = await res.json()
      setResponse(json)
      setIsLoading(false)
      if (res.status === 200) {
        return json
      }
      throw { msg: json.msg }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
      setError(error)
      throw error
    }
  }
  return { response, error, isLoading, fetchData }
}

export default useFetch
```

Comment: Thanks again for all the help with this. I just posted the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to solve this.

To not change your code base too much. I would go with a **store** with a **provider** and a **hook**. There are many store libraries out there.

Here is a tiny version which also can be used outside React rendering.
https://github.com/storeon/storeon

This was just one example of a very small store I could find that might fit the bill.

Using a store library outside React could look like:

```
import store from './path/to/my/store.js;'

// Read data
const state = store.get();

// Save data in the store
store.dispatch('foo/bar', myToken);
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using an axios interceptor (see answer) so it turns out I didn't even need a store. Same basic concept though. I needed to get the token and hold on to it somewhere it would be available to axios and I wasn't sure when to do that. If I were going to put it in a store, I would do it in the same way I'm passing it to that interceptor in the response - much like your example.

Comment: Note that Auth0 advises against storing a token because of security concerns: https://auth0.com/blog/complete-guide-to-react-user-authentication/#Calling-an-API (search for: "You should not store tokens in localStorage.")